# Call a cmd.exe bat.-like command with python

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

i need some help with this...
I have a program installed on my computer that i want to call to calculate some things and give me an output-file...

in Matlab the command "dos()" does the job giving me also the cmd screen output in matlab.

I need this to work in python but i am making something wrong.

```
data='file.csv -v'
db=' -d D:\directory\bla\something.db'
anw='"D:\Program Files\bla\path\to\anw.exe"' + db + ' -i' + data
```

"anw" output is this one:

```
>>> anw

'"D:\\Program Files\\bla\\path\\to\\anw.exe" -d D:\\directory\\bla\\something.db -i file.csv -v' 
## without the "" it does not work either

import subprocess as sb    
p= sb.Popen('cmd','/K', anw) ## '/C' does not work either
```

i get the following error message from cmd.exe inside the python shell

```
Windows cannot find "\"D:\Program Files\bla\path\to\anw.exe"" Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.
```

this line runs when i make a bat. file out of it.
it runs in matlab via "dos(anw)" so what is wrong here?
ps: i have blanks in my command... could this be the problem? i do not know where the first "\" comes from in the cmd. exe error message

Comment: unfortunately this does not work either...

Comment: i did this shlex.split(anw) to be sure the argument is converted right for the Popen() command now i get no error message but it does not create the file as i wanted

Comment: i am not english so i had to translate everything...<br/>  cmd.exe finds a data i put there before-in python it works, too :<br/> `directory of   C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\New Folder

10.11.2013  23:35            11.203 file.out
               1 Data,         11.203 Bytes

     Number of shown data:
               1 Data,         11.203 Bytes
               0 Directories,  3.579.940.864 Bytes`

Comment: `sb.Popen(['cmd','/K','D:\\Program Files\\bla\\path\\to\\anw.exe', '-d', 'D:\directory\bla\something.db' ,'-i','file.csv', '-v'])`  returns <subprocess.Popen object at 0x0000000004BABBE0>
C:\Users\userx>

Comment: maybe i know what the problem is... in order to run my command i have to move the directory to a usb drive(!), because my input file lies there Popen() sees my commands as "one line" commands so i first have to find out how i can tell python to execute multiple commands cmd.exe window!  1.D:  2.cd D:\path\to\file.csv  3. "the actual command for the run!"

Answer (score 0):

for now i created a bat. file with all the stuff cmx.de should do in the specific directory where the input file lies...

i just had to tell python to change directory with

```
import os
os.chdir("D:\working\directory")
os.system(r'D:\working\directory\commands.bat')
```

it works good and gives me the output of cmd directly in the python shell